# SQL-Select a column from a table that has two or more "instances" in another table

Tags: sql

1. I have this `table1` with column `t1_id` as PK.
2. I have this `table2` with columns `t1_id_1` and `t1_id_2` as FK from `table1`. `table2` also has columns `qty_t1` and `qty_t2` so I can store quantities used for each 'instance' of `t1_id`.
3. I also have this `table3` with column `t1_id` as FK from `table1` and column `t1_qty` to store a quantity associated to it.

All good so far. But...now I need a report to compare if `t1_id` has been stored in `table2` and `table3`, and if so, what is the `SUM` and `COUNT` balance for each. It would look like:

```
       |SUM from table3 | SUM from table2 | SUM Dif | Same with COUNT |..
t1_id1 |      15        |      7          |   8     |         ''      |..
t1_id2 |      45        |      50         |  -5     |         ''      |..
t1_id3,4,n.....
```

I'm a total beginner at SQL, I had never needed before to solve this kind of scenario. My try is:

```
select SUM(t3.t1_id),SUM(t2.t1_id1),SUM(t2.t1_id2),..same with COUNT 
from table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3 where t1.t1_id=t3.t1_id and 
(t1.t1_id=t2.t1_id1 or t1.t1_id=t2.t1_id2) GROUP BY ...
```

I can't figure out how join `SUM(t2.t1_id1),SUM(t2.t1_id2)` so I get one column with the SUM of the item whether it was stored as `t1_id1` OR `t1_id2` in `table2`.

This is the most clear and generic way I came up with to write it down in a post. Hope you can help me get this sorted out.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expect result.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to `LEFT JOIN` `table2` and `table3` to `table1`, `GROUP BY` the ID and use `sum()` and `count()`. Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.t1_id,
       sum(t3.t1_qty) "SUM from table3",
       sum(t21.qty_t1) + sum(t22.qty_t2) "SUM from table2",
       sum(t3.t1_qty) - sum(t21.qty_t1) - sum(t22.qty_t2) "SUM Dif",
       count(t3.t1_id) "COUNT from table3",
       count(t21.t1_id_1) + count(t22.t1_id_2) "COUNT from table2",
       count(t3.t1_id) - count(t21.t1_id_1) + count(t22.t1_id_2) "COUNT Dif"
       FROM table1 t1
            LEFT JOIN table2 t21
                      ON t2a.t1_id_1 = t1.t1_id
            LEFT JOIN table2 t22
                      ON t22.t1_id_2 = t1.t1_id
            LEFT JOIN table3 t3
                      ON t3.t1_id = t1.t1_id
       GROUP BY t1.t1_id;
```

(I assumed you want both values for `table2` together. If not, you'll have to split the addition of the sums and counts.)